# mysql select int as currency or convert int to currency format?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to convert an int while selecting to an currency format.  I can concat the '$' symbol but how do you place the ,'s in?  Like turning int =1000 into $1,000?

Or there is one function that can do it all?  Is there a string replacement?

Comment: Such presentation-style logic probably belongs in your application, rather than at the database layer.

Comment: @eggyal or maybe I'm just running a report out of my db admin software..

Answer (score 84, accepted):

FORMAT() function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

```
SELECT CONCAT('$', FORMAT(val, 2)) ... ;
```

Comment: And if you want the number formatting to match your locale, you can specify the locale as third parameter to `FORMAT`, e.g.: `FORMAT(val, 2, 'de_DE')`