# how to put comma in a money data type such like Decimal

Tags: mysql

I have a column by the name of `Currency` in which I store monetary values. I have set the data type of this column to `decimal`. My question is can I have comma's after 3 digits when i am displaying the money on a webpage.

For example I would like to display it as: `USD980,443,22.00`

Currently its displaying like this: `USD98044322.00`

Is it possible, or are there any other ways to do that, because I have seen it in websites lots of times.

Comment: Formatting is not MySQL's job, you do this either in PHP with [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or in another serverside platform with the features available there. And please don't just put crap in your question to evade the bad content filter, just improve your post instead - [it's not that hard](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16808084/revisions).

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556404/mysql-select-int-as-currency-or-convert-int-to-currency-format

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would want to do that in your server-side language so as to take the load off the DB, for example in PHP:

```
USD<?php echo number_format($dollarsAndCents, 2)?>
```

But if you're dead set on doing it in MySQL, here's how:

```
SELECT Format(dollarsAndCents, 2);
```