# MYSQL select to convert numbers to million,billions format

Tags: mysql, currency-formatting

i have simple mysql query

```
select count(total_profit)as profit from sales_profits
```

i get some thing like this as result `profit=25000000000`. What i want is some like this `profit=25,000,000,000`, is there some way by which we can do it in MYSQL?

Comment: You don't want to convert. You want to format. See the manual for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT(total_profit), 0) AS profit 
FROM sales_profits
```

Comment: it is very close to what i want but it does something like this `25,000,000,000.00` a dot and 2 trailing zeros, which i dont want

Comment: Simple! I've changed the number from `2` to `0`. Your purpose will serve now!

Answer (score 0):

[Format function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) as answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556404/mysql-select-int-as-currency-or-convert-int-to-currency-format)