# Format column number to currency

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, currency

I'm pulling a number from a MySQL database column and **I want to format that number as currency.**  For instance, the column value is `'85000000'` and I want that to be formatted as `'$85,000,000'`.

I've tried a few methods but can't seem to get it to work.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question answer your problem.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556404/mysql-select-int-as-currency-or-convert-int-to-currency-format>

Comment: If you want to do the formatting outside of the query use `number_format()` http://php.net/number_format

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$value = 85000000;

echo "$".number_format($value, 2, '.', ',');

?>
```

If you don't want any decimal places, change the 2 to 0.

Comment: Yes, that works. But how do I replace the 85000000 with a query from the database.  I know this is probably a dumb question, but I am fairly new to php.  For instance, I need $value = $row_NumberRow['Number']; but I know that doesn't work.