# Producing Dollar Amount Output from SQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

I need help producing a dollar amount where it has the Guar Liability , Guar Total, and Rem Balance tables. Right now, it's producing a decimal style number that's hard to read for staff. Where would you add in the SQL language to only pull $ amount? Any help would be appreciated. SQL query is:

```
select top 10 b.date_of_service as DOS
             ,b.GUARANTOR_ID as Guarantor
             ,b.service_status_value as [Status]
             ,b.guarantor_liability as [Guar Liability]
             ,b.guarantor_total_payments as [Guar Total Payments]
             ,b.remaining_balance as [Rem Balance]
             ,b.CLAIM_NUMBER as [Claim #]
from SYSTEM.billing_tx_charge_detail b
where(b.GUARANTOR_ID = "100")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "110")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "111")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "112")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "113")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "114")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "115")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "119")
     and (b.FACILITY = ?FACILITY)
     and (b.PATID = ?PATID)
order by b.date_of_service desc;
```

Comment: So you are aware, as your `where` clause is currently written your `and` and `or` operators will not be working as you would want them to.  Currently *any* record with a `GUARANTOR_ID` of any one of those values will be returned regardless of whether they match `'FACILITY` and `?PATID`

Comment: Thanks iamdave for that clarification. so where would the where clause need to go if I wanted the values to match Facility and PatID

Comment: You need to put each set of logical comparisons that you want to be evaluated as one block in their own set of parentheses.  For example, `where a = 1 and b = 2 or c = 3` will return all records where `c = 3` regardless of the value in `a` or `b`.  Whereas `where a = 1 and (b = 2 or c = 3)` will return only rows where `a = 1` *and* either `b = 2` or `c = 3`.

Comment: In your case, it would appear you want to use `where b.GUARANTOR_ID in('100','110','111','112','113','114','115','119') and b.FACILITY = ?FACILITY and b.PATID = ?PATID` which will return any record where the `GUARANTOR_ID` is in the provided list *and* the `FACILITYID` and `PATID` values are both correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select int as currency or convert int to currency format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556404/mysql-select-int-as-currency-or-convert-int-to-currency-format) - Answer applies to any numeric type, not necessarily int.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and round the result down to the nearest integer using FLOOR. Something like this.

```
select top 10 b.date_of_service as DOS
             ,b.GUARANTOR_ID as Guarantor
             ,b.service_status_value as [Status]
             ,FLOOR(b.guarantor_liability) as [Guar Liability]
             ,b.guarantor_total_payments as [Guar Total Payments]
             ,b.remaining_balance as [Rem Balance]
             ,b.CLAIM_NUMBER as [Claim #]
from SYSTEM.billing_tx_charge_detail b
where(b.GUARANTOR_ID = "100")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "110")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "111")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "112")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "113")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "114")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "115")
     or (b.GUARANTOR_ID = "119")
     and (b.FACILITY = ?FACILITY)
     and (b.PATID = ?PATID)
order by b.date_of_service desc;
```