# Add currency symbol in returned column in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to add a currency symbol.
What i did:

```
select department,round(sum(total),0) ||"€"  as n from members 
          group by department
```

it gives this:

```
     department         n
1       a      5451077.0<U+0080>
2       b      3540614.0<U+0080>
3       c      4343046.0<U+0080>
4       d      332388.0<U+0080>
5       e      116737.0<U+0080>
```

Comment: Normally you would do that in the view layer of your program instead directly in SQL.

Comment: You would do this from whatever program you are fetching the data from.

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Whatever tool you're using does not handle Unicode correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556404/mysql-select-int-as-currency-or-convert-int-to-currency-format

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
select department,(round(sum(total),0) ||'€')  as n from members 
          group by department
```

Comment: You mean with the parenthesis and the single quote? I've already tried it, it gives the result i posted.same as the version above it.

Comment: Turns out it doesn't accept the Euro symbol.Do you know how to put the commas as money 1.000 for example?